# What is the correct dart syntax?

Tags: flutter, dart, syntax

How do I do this in dart syntax, how do you read it?
The value must be between 3 to 20 characters

Following does not work:

```
validator: (value) {
                    return value != null &&
                           value.length < 3 &&
                           value.length > 20
                        ? "Title between 3 ~ 20 characters"
                        : null;
                    }
```

```
validator: (value) {
    return value != null &&
          value.length > 10 &&
          value is int
      ? "Number to big"
      : null;
},
```

Following does work but only for less than 3 chars:

```
validator: (value) {
                    return value != null &&
                           value.length < 3 
                        ? "Title between 3 ~ 20 characters"
                        : null;
                    }
```

Comment: you have to return null if validation is ok, otherwise you return error string, you did the opposite

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is no value? Should that trigger the error, or not?

Comment: you have reversed the "<" and ">"
"value != null && value.length < 3 && value.length > 20" to "value != null && value.length > 3 && value.length < 20"

Comment: People try too hard to make this a single expression.  I'd have a series of tests and string returns for various failures:  if (v == null) return "please enter a string";  if (v.length < 3 or v.length > 20) return "string must be between 3 and 20 chars"; return null;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> value length > 3 and value length < 20 if it's true null(valid) else return message "Title between 3 ~ 20 characters"

```
validator: (value) {
     return value!=null && value.length > 3 && value.length < 20
          ? null
          : "Title between 3 ~ 20 characters";
    },
```

Comment: You introduced a bug. The `!` should not be there, the original solution was perfectly fine.

Comment: How about this one?

validator: (value) {
                                        return value != null &&
                                                value.length > 10 &&
                                                value is int
                                            ? "Number to big"
                                            : null;
                                      },